# Gson parse map object without key

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2

can someone explain me, how I can parse JSON

```
{
"5": {
    "NumPossibleAchievements": "2",
    "PossibleScore": "15",
    "NumAchieved": 0,
    "ScoreAchieved": 0,
    "NumAchievedHardcore": 0,
    "ScoreAchievedHardcore": 0
},
"1838": {
    "NumPossibleAchievements": "48",
    "PossibleScore": "400",
    "NumAchieved": "48",
    "ScoreAchieved": "400",
    "NumAchievedHardcore": "48",
    "ScoreAchievedHardcore": "400"
},
"7634": {
    "NumPossibleAchievements": 0,
    "PossibleScore": 0,
    "NumAchieved": 0,
    "ScoreAchieved": 0,
    "NumAchievedHardcore": 0,
    "ScoreAchievedHardcore": 0
}
}
```

Now I've class that I want use for response

```
public class UserProgress {

private Map<String, Progress> userProgress;

public Map<String, Progress> getUserProgress() {
    return userProgress;
}
}
```

Also class that represent inner object in this map

```
public class Progress {

@SerializedName("NumPossibleAchievements")
private String numPossibleAchievements;
@SerializedName("PossibleScore")
private String possibleScore;
@SerializedName("NumAchieved")
private int numAchieved;
@SerializedName("ScoreAchieved")
private int scoreAchieved;
@SerializedName("NumAchievedHardcore")
private int numAchievedHardcore;
@SerializedName("ScoreAchievedHardcore")
private int scoreAchievedHardcore;

.....
```

And custom deserializer that should parse this type JSON to normal object. This deserializer I added to retrofit converter.

```
public class UserProgressDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<UserProgress> {

@Override
public UserProgress deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    final JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
    final Map<String, Progress> parameters = readParametersMap(jsonObject);
    final UserProgress result = new UserProgress();

    if (parameters != null) result.setUserProgress(parameters);
    return result;
}

@Nullable
private Map<String, Progress> readParametersMap(@NonNull final JsonObject jsonObject) {
    final JsonElement paramsElement = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject();
    if (paramsElement == null) return null;

    final JsonObject parametersObject = paramsElement.getAsJsonObject();
    final Map<String, Progress> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : parametersObject.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        Progress value = new Gson().fromJson(entry.getValue().getAsString(), Progress.class);
        parameters.put(key, value);
    }
    return parameters;
}
}
```

And my request

```
@GET("API_GetUserProgress.php")
Flowable<UserProgress> getUserProgress(@Query("u") @NonNull String userName,
                                                     @Query("i") String gamesCSV);
```

Request work, in raw body I see that JSON, but object contains empty map. I tested with breakpoints, but it never goes into deserializer. Now my idea is create custom function that will parse JSON string from response raw body, but this will be spike.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using [Gson converter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/gson)?

Answer (score 0):

***UPD:***
Seems like GSON accepts **Map** for *objects out of the box* and cast those objects to **LinkedTreeMap**. So, all we needed was to change request return type.

```
Flowable<Map<String, Progress>> getUserProgress(@Query("u") @NonNull String userName,
                                                @Query("i") String gamesCSV);
```

**REDUNDANT**

I had no success with custom deserializer, so I implemented new function that accepts JSON string from **raw response**, maps result to list of required objects. And now it looks like

```
Flowable<ResponseBody> flowable = USERS_API.getUserProgress(userName, gameIDsCSV);
    return manageRequestWithMapper(flowable, responseBody -> {
        String body = responseBody.string();
        JSONObject yourJSON = new JSONObject(body);
        Iterator<String> keysIterator = yourJSON.keys();
        List<Progress> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        while (keysIterator.hasNext()) {
            String key = keysIterator.next();
            JSONObject actualObj = (JSONObject) yourJSON.get(key);
            tempList.add((new Gson()).fromJson(actualObj.toString(), Progress.class));
        }
        return tempList;
    });
```